# annotate a label to query based on thresholds that it falls within

Tags: python, django, compare, threshold, annotate

I am trying to label my results based on two properties of my query set which falls within each combination of two threshold of another query. Here is a piece of code for clarification:

```
threshold_query = threshold.objects.all()
main_query = main.ojbects.values(
    'Athreshold', 'Bthreshold'
).annotate(
    Case(
        When(
            Q(Avalue__lte=threshold_query['Avalue'])
            & Q(Bvalue__lte=threshold_query['Bvalue']),
            then=Value(threshold_query['label'])
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

the model for thresholds is like:

```
class threshold(models.Model):
    Avalue = models.FloatField(default=0.1)
    Bvalue = models.FloatField(default=0.3)
    label = models.CharField(default='Accepted')
```

so there is a matrix that decides the labels, for example if there are two thresholds {'Avalue': 0.4, 'Bvalue': 0.6, 'label': 'rejected'} and {'Avalue': 0.7, 'Bvalue': 0.7, 'label': Accepted} if you demonstrate the Avalues on horizontal axis (naming the row of the matrix) and Bvalues on vertical axis (naming the column of the matrix), the combination of these two thresholds decides the value of the cell which would be 'Accepted' or 'Rejected'.
Is it possible to obtain what is in my mind using one query?
my purpose is to minimize the number of queries due to enormity of Data.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "so there is a matrix that decides the labels."

Comment: sure. for example if there are two thresholds  {'Avalue': 0.4, 'Bvalue': 0.6, 'label': 'rejected'} and {'Avalue': 0.7, 'Bvalue': 0.7, 'label': Accepted}
if you demonstrate the Avalues on horizontal axis (naming the row of the matrix) and Bvalues on vertical axis (naming the column of the matrix), the combination of these two thresholds decides the value of the cell which would be Accepted or Rejected.

Comment: the purpose is kind of mapping the calculated values of main query to fuzzy thresholds that have been determined by experts. @RajKris

Comment: So are you asking whether to do the entire thing in one query, that is fetching the threshold values from 'threshold' model and annotating the 'main' using the threshold values using a single query?

Comment: exactly. Is it possible? @RajKris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532182/is-it-possible-to-build-a-case-when-statement-as-string-and-run-it-in-annotatio?noredirect=1#comment82021321_47532182) in a follow up question, I ended up using When as a list passed to Case, So the code is something like:

```
args = []
for any_threshold in Threshold.objects.all():
    label = any_threshold.ThresholdValue
    args.append( When(MainAvalue__lte= Avalue,MainBValue__lte= Bvalue,then=Value(label, output_field=CharField()) ))
```

and the annotation is like:

```
MainLevel = Case(*args, default=Value('Rejected'))
```

P.S: Could not use 'subquery' based on the reason explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504879/annotate-a-label-to-query-based-on-thresholds-that-it-falls-within/47532588#comment82091447_47532588)

Answer (score 0):

On Django 1.11+, you can use subqueries:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

Main.objects.annotate(
    label=Subquery(
        Threshold.objects.filter(
            Avalue__gte=OuterRef('Athreshold'),
            Bvalue__gte=OuterRef('Bthreshold'),
        ).values('label')[:1]
    )
)
```

If the values can match more than one threshold, you need to define some consistent ordering on the inner query.

Comment: Thanks @knbk. However the 'Avalue' and 'Bvalue' are annotated in the main object, therefor not available in the 'subquery' and lack of foreign key from threshold to main model make it impossible to annotate it in 'subquery'. Is there a workaround?